# Java Spring Friendly Url mapping issues

Tags: java, spring, mapping, friendly-url

I've been trying to implement friendly url mapping in my first Java spring site. I've been following this tutorial. http://outbottle.com/spring-3-web-mvc-friendly-url-using-requestmapping-variable-uri/

My current mapping works well with id's as parameters. localhost:8080/user?id=1312321321

```
/*
 * User
*/
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value={"/user","/user/{id}"})
public ModelAndView profileDisplay(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id
) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {
    ServiceSerlvet.appendSesssion(request);
    //get search ALL users
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    List<DBObject> searchResponse = PersonController.searchUsers(searchQuery);

    //System.out.println("response from search user method: "+searchResponse);

    return new ModelAndView("user", "people", searchResponse);
}
```

My web xml currently looks like this... its working but is it correct to write out various url mapping like this? I take it the * is a wild card to allow say /user/22222?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
              </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>


    <url-pattern>/gallery/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/galleryupload/*</url-pattern>

    <url-pattern>/delete/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/edit/*</url-pattern>

    <url-pattern>/search/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/members/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/messages/*</url-pattern>

    <url-pattern>/index/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/register/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsoninterests/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsonlocations/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsonmembers/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsonuniqueuser/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I try and adapt my code to take just a name like this localhost:8080/user/john

it breaks - but I am unsure how to set the mapping in the web.xml, do I set the mapping like this in web.xml?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView profileDisplay(
                @PathVariable(value="id") String id,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {

    ServiceSerlvet.appendSesssion(request);
            //get search ALL users
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                searchQuery.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));
            List<DBObject> searchResponse = PersonController.searchUsers(searchQuery);

            //System.out.println("response from search user method: "+searchResponse);

            return new ModelAndView("user", "people", searchResponse);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I map every request to the dispatcher servlet in web.xml.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
              </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then in your Controllers use @RequestMapping annotations to define the more granular mappings:

```
    @RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ModelAndView profileDisplay(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id
    ) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I see - so it should just be <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> - so as not to enforce a specific pattern - this way the mapping gets accepted? Would this approach work with the PathVariable approach? so accept /user/john or /search/football/seriousrelationship/indiancurry - like multiple parameters?

Comment: It works with the path variable approach, your just running every request through the dispatcher and relying upon the mappings you have established in your controllers.  The only issue is that resource files like css, js and images will be sent through the controller.  Spring provides some configuration to avoid this.  Look at any maven archetype for spring mvc and it should include this config.